# Banner not showing in html page when in div and can't find it when inspected

Tags: html, css

I am making a website about pets. I crafted the pictures that were needed but .. When I put the banner , it does not show up. When inspecting the page - it is not there. If I put it right after the body tag , it will show , also when inspected. But it won't be what I want.

```
  <body>

<ul class="nav">

    <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html">Pets</a>
    </div>

    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="pets.html">Pets</a></li>
    <li><a href="rates.html">Rates</a></li>
    <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>

</ul>

<div class="banner>
    <img class="banner-image" src="testbanner.png">
</div>
```

I don't get what the problem is.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<ul>` can **only** have a `<li>` as a child, no divs. As for the banner not showing you'll need to update your question and post a [mcve]

Comment: The only allowed direct child element of `ul` is `li`.

Comment: What? Why? Should I post the whole code?

Comment: You have an adblocker active in your browser?

Comment: Okay. But that is not the problem. The banner is outside the <ul>.

Comment: I have no adblockers. Incognito also won't show the image. The logo is working fine.

Comment: Again, post a [mcve] in your question please so that we can reproduce the issue. Have you checked your browser's developer tools to look for errors?

Comment: `<div class="banner>` must be `<div class="banner">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with this I can see.

```
<ul class="nav">

    <!--1: You cannot have a div directly inside a <ul> tag. Move it somewhere else-->
    <!--<div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html">Pets</a>
    </div>-->

    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="pets.html">Pets</a></li>
    <li><a href="rates.html">Rates</a></li>
    <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>

</ul>
<!--2: You must end the string describing the class. This is what is preventing the banner to work-->
<div class="banner">
    <img class="banner-image" src="testbanner.png">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what your point #2 refers to, and your #1 point has been mentioned numerous times already, so there's no need to post it yet again

Comment: @j08691 Point 2 refers to the fact that the class="banner needs an end quotation

Comment: This question needs to be closed as off-topic due to a typo

Answer (score -1):

You can't put a div directly in ul.
Assuming you want the banner inherit the nav class, you can add a parent div that contain your banner and the list like this :

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html">Pets</a>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="pets.html">Pets</a></li>
        <li><a href="rates.html">Rates</a></li>
        <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

otherwise if you are not bothered by the bullets or if you hide them with css you can put the banner between `<li> </ li>` :

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><div class="logo"><a href="index.html">Pets</a></div></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="pets.html">Pets</a></li>
    <li><a href="rates.html">Rates</a></li>
    <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: While this is correct, it does not provide an answer to the question.

Comment: I do not see any question, just a statement :) ... visibility on the css would be useful to understand

Comment: Then why did you even bother to answer it if you saw no question? Wait for the OP to clarify or work on getting enough rep to leave comments.

Comment: Just trying to help... I think we should be able to leave comments before having the right to answer but this is only my opinion